# Pie-chart in Apache Superset

Tags: pie-chart, apache-superset

I want to create a Pie-chart which shows different alert levels(High, Medium and Low) along with their values, how can I achieve this in Apache Superset?

Apache Superset expects only one metric for the Pie-chart.
I have attached my mock data and the expected outcome below.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoyjt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jnK6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a dataset from your csv or a database connection, and then you can create the chart from that dataset.

For the Pie-chart, you need to aggregate the data. You can choose the "Alert Level" column as your dimension and use a metric like "SUM(Value)" as your metric and in the "Group By" section, select the "Alert Level" column